# Having problems getting the Googe Map Fragment call the onMapReady

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

So the issue that I'm having is that i'm not sure how to access the map to set the initial location. The Fragment is always coming back NULL so it seems not to call the getMapReady function. I'm just not sure how to correctly reference the map widget in the layout so it will call the setUp for the map correctly.

**THE LAYOUT**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.user.thisweekintown.CalendarFragment">



    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/mySwipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/bus_list_recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/businessslocation"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**The CODE**

```
class BusListFragment : Fragment(),OnMapReadyCallback {
    lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    var mapView: SupportMapFragment? = null
    var totaladd:String? = null
.........
```

**AND THEN**

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bus_list,container,false)
        var social_recycle: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.bus_list_recycle)

        Log.d("should be calling", "onMapReady")

        swipey = view.findViewById(R.id.mySwipe)
        swipey.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN);

        swipey.setOnRefreshListener(SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener { setupRecycle(true) })
        calFrPrefs = context?.getSharedPreferences("main_prefs",0)

        (activity as MainActivity).getSupportActionBar()?.setTitle(calFrPrefs!!.getString("current_town_name","No Town")+ " Businesses")
        setupRecycle(false)
        return view

    }
```

**AND THEN**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mapView = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.businessslocation) as? SupportMapFragment
        Log.d("isMapView", mapView.toString())

        mapView?.getMapAsync(this)

    }
```

**It should call the following**

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap){
        mMap = googleMap
        Log.d("onMapready", "MapReady")
        val cphbusiness = LatLng(42.187, 71.3065)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(cphbusiness).title("Her"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16.0F))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cphbusiness))

        val geocoder = Geocoder(context)
        if (geocoder is Geocoder) {
            var list: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocationName(totaladd, 1)
            if(list.size >0) {
                var mAddress: Address = list.get(0)
                Log.d("latitiude", mAddress.latitude.toString())
                Log.d("latitiude", mAddress.longitude.toString())
                var address1 = LatLng(mAddress.latitude, mAddress.longitude)
                changeMap(address1)
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to find Valid Location...Centering on Random place", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                changeMap(cphbusiness)
            }
        } else {

        }

    }


    fun changeMap(myLL: LatLng) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLL))
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(myLL))

    }
```

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager` is used for fragments inside fragments - try using fragmentManager.

Comment: Did you have some error? Add the stacktrace if it was printed

Comment: @MaratZangiev no just that the fragment returns null

Comment: @Andy         mapView = fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.businessslocation) as? MapFragment
 still ends up null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolve this issue by changing fragments name from `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` to `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Answer (score 0):

Access the fragment via the Activity fragment manager:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Fragments added to XML via <fragment> tag get added to the ACTIVITY fragment manager
    // so access the fragment through that instead.
    mapView = activity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.businessslocation) as? SupportMapFragment
    Log.d("isMapView", mapView.toString())

    mapView?.getMapAsync(this)
}
```

Or add the MapFragment via code, per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#add_map_code).

Hope that helps!

Comment: No dice still returns mapView.toStriing as Null
 mapView = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.businessslocation) as? MapFragment

Comment: The parent of the map fragment is a fragmet itself  called when II click on a navigation button         ib5.setOnClickListener({ v -> changeFragment(frag5,false,null) })